# Lubuntu won't boot on my laptop

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Recently I tried to boot lubuntu on my laptop, but it just stopped after I clicked the install opiton. I later tried to boot win xp, and it worked. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information on your computer at all, also were you booting from CD/DVD or USB FLash ?

If it was a disc then make sure the .iso file was downloaded properly and if using the torrent download force a re-check...  Also burn the .iso to disc at the slowest possible speed...

If using a USB Flash Drive, try unetbootin instead of Startup Disc Creator to make your stick bootable...